# ios:Unable to satisfy constraints, from Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm getting the "Unable to satisfy constraints," but I'm setting all my constraints in storyboard. I thought that this would ensure that there were no conflicts. What could be causing this error?

Note: I do have a container view which contains another viewcontroller. Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: Setting your constraints in storyboard doesn't ensure you have no conflicts, since the view size changes when the program runs (orientation changes, screen size change, etc). Also sometimes some views will load with frame sizes of 0, so that could mess up constraints too.